# Standardizing LocalDate.getDayOfWeek().getValue() in Java.time

Tags: java, java-time

```
int dayOfWeek = LocalDate.now().getDayOfWeek.getValue();
```

This code returns a different number depending on where you are (Monday might be 1 or 2). is there a way for my application to standardize this? so that Monday always returns 1 and Sunday always returns 7?

Comment: What if you use your own mapping? Map Monday to 1, Tuesday to 2, etc., that way, when you call `getDayOfWeek` and get the day, you won't have to worry about any inconsistency?

Comment: Your question is invalid. `LocalDate.now().getDayOfWeek.getValue();` always returns 1 on Mondays. See the `DayofWeek` enum and the source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [java.time.temporal.WeekFields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html):

```java
WeekFields weekFields = WeekFields.of(Locale.FRANCE); // defines Monday as day 1
System.out.println(LocalDate.now().get(weekFields.dayOfWeek()));
```